# How to determine the codec of an audio file on Windows?

Tags: audio, codec

I need to find the codec of an audio file. How can I do this?

Do I need to write code to do this or is there a simpler way?

Please help me. If possible share helpful links.

Comment: OS/language? if a general question try G-SPOT; http://www.headbands.com/gspot/

Comment: You could try [gspot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/).

Answer (score 12):

The good old `file` utility will reveal lots of information about audio files, sometimes including the codec:

```
$ file X.wav 
X.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 16000 Hz
```

Comment: @Nobody here is the man page: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file. It is a command provided with lots of unix systems.

Comment: @Nobody just clarify the question, modifying both the title and the body, and somebody that knows the answer will come and help you. I don't use windows, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Nobody, you can use cygwin to get access to the `file` command.  Free and easy to use (if you can use a commandline).

Comment: I have an "Apple Lossless audio file" and an "AAC audio file" (this is according to iTunes: Get Info: File).  Using the file utility yields identical output for both files: fileName.m4a: ISO Media, Apple iTunes ALAC/AAC-LC (.M4A) Audio

Answer (score 5):

@bhebsquines

"It is important to distinguish between a file format and an audio codec. A codec performs the encoding and decoding of the raw audio data while the data itself is stored in a file with a specific audio file format. Although most audio file formats support only one type of audio data (created with an audio coder), a multimedia container format (as Matroska or AVI) may support multiple types of audio and video data." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_file_format

The application gspot does a good job of pulling codecs from audio and video files.

http://www.headbands.com/gspot/

run it and drag a file into the window. It will pull all of the data from there. Note that some audio files will not display a codec as they are made from "Raw" audio.

Answer (score -6):

You can identify your codec by extenion name itself example file1audio.mp3 or fileaudio.avi, .mp3, .avi will be your file type or codec, you can use k-lite codec pack for your different type audio format. use this link http://www.free-codecs.com/download/k_lite_codec_pack.htm

Comment: you can encode/decode your audio defend on your file format so you need to check your file format first.